# "Bind address needs a port" running docker-compose to start containers

Tags: laravel, docker, composer-php, laradock

```
$ andrzej@andrzej-Latitude-E6230:~/Desktop/Projects/laradock$ docker-compose up -d mysql caddy workspace

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.17.1', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 68, in main
    command()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 118, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 37, in project_from_options
    override_dir=options.get('--project-directory'),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 99, in get_project
    host=host, environment=environment
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 71, in get_client
    environment=environment, tls_version=get_tls_version(environment)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 95, in docker_client
    return APIClient(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 109, in __init__
    base_url, IS_WINDOWS_PLATFORM, tls=bool(tls)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/utils/utils.py", line 373, in parse_host
    "Bind address needs a port: {0}".format(addr))
docker.errors.DockerException: Bind address needs a port: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Please provide your docker-compose file. You can format it as code by prefixing every line with 4 spaces.

Comment: You'll have to explain better the problem here, with just pasting the problem doesn't help much.

Comment: I made a change in Caddyfile to set root /var/www/playmatec-web/public and then I tried to create a container but it returned an error that the bind address needs a port.

Comment: Woah. That is the largest docker-compose file I have ever seen !

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mCk5ziau -> docker-compose file

Comment: You _must_ provide it as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53734410/edit) to your question.